# How can I pass parameters to the OnSuccess function of the AjaxOptions class in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

How can I pass parameters to the `OnSuccess` function of the `AjaxOptions` class in ASP.NET MVC?

Here's my code but it doesn't work:

```
<%= Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", 
                    "Delete", 
                    "MyController", 
                    New With {.id = record.ID}, 
                    New AjaxOptions With 
                    {
                        .Confirm = "Delete record?", 
                        .HttpMethod = "Delete", 
                        .OnSuccess = "updateCount('parameter')"
                    })
%>
```

---

**UPDATE**

Setting the `OnSuccess` property to `(function(){updateCount('parameter');})` solved my problem:

```
<%= Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", 
                    "Delete", 
                    "MyController", 
                    New With {.id = record.ID}, 
                    New AjaxOptions With 
                    {
                        .Confirm = "Delete record?", 
                        .HttpMethod = "Delete", 
                        .OnSuccess = "(function(){updateCount('parameter');})"
                    })
%>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to use a jQuery selector to populate a value from a field in the page:

```
<%= Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", 
                    "Delete", 
                    "MyController", 
                    New With {.id = record.ID}, 
                    New AjaxOptions With 
                    {
                        .Confirm = "Delete record?", 
                        .HttpMethod = "Delete", 
                        .OnSuccess = "updateCount($('#SomeField).val()))"
                    })
%>
```

Also take a look here: [Can I pass a parameter with the OnSuccess event in a Ajax.ActionLink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792441/can-i-pass-a-parameter-with-the-onsuccess-event-in-a-ajax-actionlink)

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing me to that link. I had looked at that post before but overlooked one of the answers.

Comment: @Dave, how can I pass the generated anchor to the success function? I tried `this`, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a MVC4 example. OnBegin, OnSuccess, OnComplete and OnFailure -functions are used to enable/disable my ajax animations. Each function passes a item Id as parameter to allow me to reuse my js functions for all my ajax sections. ajaxOnbegin() shows a gif and ajaxOnsuccess hides it again.

```
<script>
@*Ajax Animation*@
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ajaxLoadingGif").hide();
    });
    function ajaxOnbegin(id) {
        //show animated gif
        $(id).show();
    }
    function ajaxOnsuccess(id) {
        //disable animated gif
        $(id).hide();
    }
    function ajaxOnfailure(id) {
        //disbale animated gif
        $(id).hide();
    }
    function ajaxOncomplete(id) {
        //disable animated gif
        $(id).hide();
    }


  </script>

@Ajax.ActionLink(linkText: " Hi", // <-- Text to display
                  actionName: "getJobCards", // <-- Action Method Name
                  routeValues: new {  searchString = ViewBag.searchString},
                  ajaxOptions: new AjaxOptions{
                               "#itemId", // <-- DOM element ID to update
                                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, 
                                HttpMethod = "GET", // <-- HTTP method
                                OnBegin =    "ajaxOnbegin('#ajaxLoadingGif')", 
                                          //="ajaxOnbegin" without parameters
                                OnSuccess =  "ajaxOnsuccess('#ajaxLoadingGif')",
                                OnComplete = "ajaxOncomplete('#ajaxLoadingGif')",
                                OnFailure =  "ajaxOnfailure('#ajaxLoadingGif')"
                                },
                                htmlAttributes: new { id = ViewBag.ajaxId }

                  )
```