# How to Hide Ajax.ActionLink after call is made

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

```
<%: Ajax.ActionLink("View Code Status", "GetCodes", "BvIndex",
        new { id = o.Id },
        new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = count.ToString() },
        new { @id = "h" + count.ToString()}) %>
```

I want to hide the link after the ajax call is made. I tried doing it  onsuccess and oncomplete methods but i was not able to do it. 
Any solution for this.

This is the way which i tried onsuccess, i was able to hide it but i am getting an error.

```
<%: Ajax.ActionLink("View Code Status", "GetCodes", "BvIndex",
        new { id = o.Id },
        new AjaxOptions {
                    OnSuccess = "functionhide("+count+")",
                    UpdateTargetId = count.ToString()
        },
        new { @id = "h" + count.ToString()})%>
```

onsuccess function

```
function functionhide(count) {
            $("#h" + (count)).hide();
        };
```

This is working fine but,I am getting an error saying,

**Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'b' is null or not an object**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<%= Ajax.ActionLink(
    "View Code Status", 
    "GetCodes", 
    "BvIndex",
    new { id = o.Id },
    new AjaxOptions {
        OnSuccess = "functionhide",
        UpdateTargetId = count.ToString() // <-- Warning you are probably having invalid markup as ids cannot start with a number
    },
    new { 
        id = "h" + count.ToString() 
    }
) %>
```

and then:

```
function functionhide() {
    $(this).hide();
}
```

Comment: Damn you, Darin!  You're too fast!

I always thought the `this` keyword referenced the `jqxhr` object from the `OnSuccess` method call... was this changed or have I always been wrong about this?

Comment: @DMactheDestroyer, IIRC this has changed in ASP.NET MVC 3 as it uses jQuery and not longer the MicrosoftAjax libraries.

Answer (score 1):

**Simple solution is to use** -

```
OnComplete="javascript:this.style.display='none'"
```

e.g.

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(
  "Hide button before ajax",
  "myAction", 
  new AjaxOptions { OnComplete="javascript:this.style.display='none'" }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792441/can-i-pass-a-parameter-with-the-onsuccess-event-in-a-ajax-actionlink) that might help you out... they noted receiving the same error message and making the `OnSuccess` value an anonymous function seemed to fix it.