# Get reference to form that submitted Ajax.BeginForm?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am using Ajax.BeginForm like this:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("PostAction", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "post", UpdateTargetId = "TargetID", OnComplete = "OnComplete" }, new { @class = "" }))
```

In the javascript method `OnComplete` how can I find the form that was submitted? (Or even the target ID)

I need to access data attributes of the forms container.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can send id or name of the form to your javascript with somethink like thsi

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("PostAction", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "post", UpdateTargetId = "TargetID", OnComplete = "OnComplete(xhr, status, 'form1')" }, new { @class = "" }))
```

javascript

```
function OnComplete(xhr, status, formName) {


    alert('Submited Form is  ' + formName);
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can pass variables through like that can you? They come through as undefined on my side of the world...?

Comment: http://johnculviner.com/post/2012/03/19/AjaxBeginForm-AjaxOptions-arguments-for-OnComplete-OnSuccess-OnFailure-and-OnBegin.aspx the reference

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/792441/can-i-pass-a-parameter-with-the-onsuccess-event-in-a-ajax-actionlink might be helpfull as well